# Adaptive Cards - Get PostBack for actions

Tags: azure, botframework, adaptive-cards

I have to use adaptive cards in certain situation. When I use these cards, I need to have some buttons that can perform different actions when clicked. Previously, I have been using Hero Cards to return data and create the buttons. I have found that postBack (for hero cards) is the way to accept the button output most effectively for me. Unfortunately, adaptive cards doesn’t seem to have postBack. Instead, I need to use Action.Submit. However, when I do this, I end up with the text from the button showing as part of the conversation. I don’t want that and need it to be consistent with postBack. I tried to use the method from this comment https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/558  (the guy has the exact same ask as me) but, it doesn’t seem to work anymore (from 2017). Any suggestions? **I'm using SDK V4 and the basic bot NodeJS build found in the Azure portal.**
Thanks for the help in advance

Adding the code for more detail:

```
    var card = {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
            {"type": "TextBlock",
            "text": answer}, 
            table],
        "actions" : [{
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": wrap(promptQuestions[0]),
            "data": promptQuestions[0] 
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": wrap(promptQuestions[1]),
            "data": promptQuestions[1]
        }]
    }

    console.log(card)
    return CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card);
```

Comment: "PostBack" is the default behavior for submit actions (meaning the text shouldn't show). Please provide the code for the Adaptive Card in question and tell us what channel you're using. Also explain what happens when you try to use the method from the GitHub issue.

Comment: I'm currently running in the emulator. This current version shows the data of the button I click on. I don't want that to show. I believe when I used the GitHub version, I got an error. I will try again to get more info.

Comment: The GitHub solution will cause the button to do nothing when I click it.

Comment: Makes sense. It's a little unfortunate that it works that way but I'll find a way around it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's no need to find a way around it. I've already explained exactly what you need to do. Did you read the blog post I linked? Why is it unfortunate?

Answer (score 1):

Submit action data is supposed to be an object and not a string. See my blog post for more information: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/